# yii check input of two non database model if equals

Tags: php, validation, yii, yii-components

I want to compare two input in my model

```
  class User extends CActiveRecord
  {
    public function tableName()
    {
        return '{{user}}';
    }

     public $newPassword;
     public $repeatPassword;
```

how can i do this using rules() . . note that $newPassword and $repeatPassword is none database model

this is my view

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'newPassword'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'newPassword',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>128)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'newPassword'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'repeatPassword'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'repeatPassword',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>128)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'repeatPassword'); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [validation](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/56/) from yii wiki

```
public function rules() {
    return array(
        array('newPassword', 'required'),
        array('repeatPassword', 'required'),
        array('newPassword', 'compare', 'compareAttribute'=>'repeatPassword'),
    );
}
```

or you can [write your own validation rule](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.model#declaring-validation-rules)

```
public function rules() {
    return array(
        array('newPassword, repeatPassword', 'safe'),
        array('newPassword', 'checkPassword'),
    );
}

public function checkPassword($attribute,$params) {
    // return if there was no password input
    if (empty($this->newPassword) && empty($this->repeatPassword)) return;

    // if password does not match repeat password add validation error
    if ($this->newPassword != $this->repeatPassword)
        $this->addError('newPassword','Password does not match the Repeat Password.');
}
```

Comment: yes i already tried that.. but when i test that it doesn't work .. and i want the field only be required if new password is filled up

Comment: you can always [write your own validator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.model#declaring-validation-rules). if you have any problems with making it work please show your code.

Comment: actually that is the code.. the first is the user model and the second one is the view.

Comment: can you give me an example of custom rules validation for new password and repeat password that is only required if new password is set? i really cannot find any example of this problem on google .. thanks

Comment: hello lapatus.. why did you set it to safe?